# Pasando variable de formulario html a nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, get, proxy

estoy creando un webproxy con nodejs para poder acceder "anónimamente" a otro sitio, entonces este es mi servidor:

```
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");
const request = require("request");
const fs = require('fs')
var server = http.createServer(onRequest);

function onRequest(req, res) {
  var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  if (queryData.url) {
    request({ url: queryData.url })
      .on("error", function(e) {
        res.end(e);
      })
      .pipe(res);
  } else {
    fs.readFile("index.html", (err, html) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }else {
        res.write(htm);
        res.end();
      }

    });
  }
}

server.listen(80);
```

que afortunadamente me carga bien la vista:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hola</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="mx-auto mt-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form class="" method="post">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="www.example.com">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inclusive el proxy me funciona, ya que solo tendría que agregar la url de la pagina que quiero visitar a la variable llamada **url** en el encabezado de la siguiente manera: http://example.com/url=www.google.com y listo, accede bien. Lo que quiero hacer es una especie de petición get para que la variable url acceda el valor del input del formulario, pero no tengo la menor idea ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Quieres que sea algo como `http://tusitio.com/?url=www.sitioingresado.com` ?

Comment: Si, asi mismo, pero con el protocolo delante http://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="www.example.com">
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Observa la propiedad `action` y `method` del `<form>`.
Con `action` le decimos a que url hacer la solicitud y con `method` de que forma hacerlo, en este caso `get`.

Ahora en el input colocamos los nombres de los valores que queremos enviar con la propiedad `name` (en este caso `url`).